# How do you deserialize an interface to an internal class of another assembly?

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer

Obviously, it is impossible to serialize/deserialize interfaces if the concrete types are *not known* to the compiler.

I have an interface-only assembly `MyInterfaces` and an assembly `MyImpl` with **internal** implementations of these interfaces. Instantiation looks like this:

```
MyInterfaces.IFoo foo = MyImpl.FooFactory.CreateFoo();
```

Here's the factory in assembly `MyImpl`:

```
IFoo CreateFoo()
{
    return new Foo(); // Internal class!
}
```

And here's the concrete `Foo` class in assembly `MyImpl`:

```
[DataContract]
internal class Foo : IFoo
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Bar
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

### Serialization is trivial

Reading the type of the factory-created `IFoo` object allows for serialization of the `IFoo` interface:

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyFooContainer),
    new Type[] { container.Foo.GetType() });
serializer.WriteObject(writer, container);
```

### Deserialization impossible?

When deserializing, the type cannot be deduced since we have no object to look at!

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyFooContainer),
    new Type[] { /* CANNOT provide other assembly's internal type! */ });
container = (MyFooContainer)serializer.ReadObject(reader);
```

I was hoping that the serialized XML would be enough for `DataContractSerializer` to determine how to create the `MyImpl.Foo` object, but no. It tells me this:

*"Error in line 1 position 269. Element 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyAssembly:Foo' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyImpl:Foo'. The deserializer has no knowledge..."*

**Q: Using `DataContractSerializer`, how do you deserialize an interface to an internal, derived class of another assembly?**

Obviously, it makes sense to have public interfaces with internal implementations. It also makes sense to allow for serialization. Please help!

More about this particular problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2008/10/04/serializing-internal-types-using-xmlserializer.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could let the factory that delivers the instances of your interface have another method to deliver a serializer to serialize/deserialize the objects. That way, the serializer can know all the internal classes.

Comment: Thanks. We'll settle for this solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are defeating the purpose of DataContractSerializer by cheating it into serializing non-public data. The design of DataContractSerializer is such that it is meant to serialize *publicly visible* and *sharable* data only. This helps achieve platform and technology independence by making it possible to share the type information in formats like WSDL.

For the functionality you are looking to achieve - it is better to use BinaryFormatter. However, then you are stuck with only .NET for de-serialization.

Comment: This is not entirely true. Since DataContractSerializer can serialize almost everything, private or read only members as well. There are scenarios when the deserialization side is implemented by an entirely different set of technologies. There is no restriction in serialization and there is no such thing as cheating, since the WSDL makes everything visible and public. It is up to the implementation on each side of the wire how they treat the serialized or deserialized data internally - which parts they publish to their consumers.